# How to check a disk for partitions for use in a script in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, disk-partitioning

I'm scripting something in Bash for Linux systems.  How would I check a disk for partitions in a robust manner?

I could use `grep`, `awk`, or `sed` to parse the output from `fdisk`, `sfdisk`, etc., but this doesn't seem to be an exact science.

I could also check if there are partitions in `/dev`, but it is also possible that the partitions exist and haven't been probed yet (via `partprobe`, as an example).

What would you recommend?

Comment: What are you trying to detect exactly? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: `sfdisk -d` produces a format that is somewhat easier to parse, although still not ideal. `kpartx -l` is even better in that regard, if you have it installed. There may be other utilities as well.

Comment: @Ethan Reisner: No catch; I'm merely just checking for partitions.  If there aren't any, the script will eventually make a new MBR partition schema and create one large partition on the drive.

Comment: `sfdisk` on RHEL 5.5 complains about GPT label. Asks me to use `parted` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I figured out a reliable way.  I accidentally learned some more features of `partprobe` while reading the man page:

```
-d     Don’t update the kernel.
-s     Show a summary of devices and their partitions.
```

Used together, I can scan a disk for partitions without updating the kernel and get a reliable output to parse.  It's still parsing text, but at least the output isn't as "human-oriented" as `fdisk` or `sfdisk`.  This also is information as read from the disk and doesn't rely on the kernel being up-to-date on the partition status for this disk.

Take a look:

On a disk with no partition table:

```
# partprobe -d -s /dev/sdb
(no output)
```

On a disk with a partition table but no partitions:

```
# partprobe -d -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: msdos partitions
```

On a disk with a partition table and one partition:

```
# partprobe -d -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: msdos partitions 1
```

On a disk with a partition table and multiple partitions:

```
# partprobe -d -s /dev/sda
/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1 2 3 4 <5 6 7>
```

It is important to note that every exit status was 0 regardless of an existing partition table or partitions.  In addition, I also noticed that the options cannot be grouped together (`partprobe -d -s /dev/sdb` works while `partprobe -ds /dev/sdb` does not).

Comment: learned something new. And this might be a better way, as you say, to be machine parsed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run:

```
lsblk
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108951

Comment: `lsblk` does not exist on RHEL 5.5

Answer (score 0):

you could also use:

```
parted  /dev/sda print 1  &> /dev/null
echo $?
```

if a partition (first partition) exist it return true and otherwise false

Answer (score 0):

### `lsblk`

If you want partition information from `lsblk`:

```
lsblk -n -o NAME,TYPE,FSTYPE,PTTYPE
```

If you want to know whether a top level block device is partitioned or not, you can check the partition type, and restrict the results to skip dependent devices. (e.g. show only `/dev/sda`, ignoring `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, etc)

For example:

```
# this device has a partition table
$ lsblk -nd -o PTTYPE /dev/sda
gpt

# this device is unformatted, and does not have a partition table
$ lsblk -nd -o PTTYPE /dev/sdd

# ^ outputs blank line

# this device does not exist
$ lsblk -nd -o PTTYPE /dev/sdf
lsblk: /dev/sdf: not a block device
$ echo $?    # non-zero exit code
32
```

To determine if a disk has a partition table using `lsblk`:

```bash
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

partitioned() {
        local DISK="$1"
        # Define PARTITION_CHECK as local here so we can capture the exit code
        # from lsblk. If we try to do it all in one go we end up capturing the
        # exit code of setting the variable as local rather than the exit code
        # of lsblk:
        # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637060/
        # https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html
        local PARTITION_CHECK
        if PARTITION_CHECK=$(lsblk -nd -o PTTYPE "$DISK" 2> /dev/null)
        then
                if [ -z "$PARTITION_CHECK" ]
                then
                        echo "${DISK}: Not partitioned"
                elif [ -n "$PARTITION_CHECK" ]
                then
                        echo "${DISK}: Partitioned"
                fi
        else
                echo "${DISK}: Could not determine partition status"
        fi
}

for DISK in /dev/sda /dev/sdc /dev/sdf test
do
        partitioned "$DISK"
        echo
done

$ ./test.sh
/dev/sda: Partitioned

/dev/sdc: Not partitioned

/dev/sdf: Could not determine partition status

test: Could not determine partition status
```

### `partx`

You could also try `partx`, which will return zero if a partition table exists, or non-zero if it does not. Note that it also returns non-zero for a whole bunch of other reasons (insufficient permission, non-existent device, etc), which complicates things if you want to know conclusively that a device is *not* partitioned:

```
# disk with partition table
$ sudo partx /dev/sda
NR  START      END  SECTORS  SIZE NAME UUID
 1 227328 62916574 62689247 29.9G      a123bcf4-5678-912d-d345-6b78f90g1234
$ echo $?
0

# unformatted disk
$ sudo partx /dev/sdd
partx: /dev/sdd: failed to read partition table
$ echo $?
1

# non-existent disk
$ sudo partx /dev/sdc
partx: stat of /dev/sdc failed: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

NOTE: `lsblk` doesn't appear to provide filesystem or partition type information for WSL virtual filesystems. It outputs a blank line above, even when `df -T` shows a filesystem type.

If you need to see *some* information about WSL virtual disks, `parted` might help (note: `sudo` required):

```
# WSL virtual disk
$ DEV=/dev/sda; sudo parted -ms "$DEV" print 2>/dev/null | grep "$DEV" | cut -d: -f 6
loop

# real gpt partitioned disk
$ DEV=/dev/sda; sudo parted -ms "$DEV" print 2>/dev/null | grep "$DEV" | cut -d: -f 6
gpt

# real unformatted disk
$ DEV=/dev/sdd; sudo parted -ms "$DEV" print 2>/dev/null | grep "$DEV" | cut -d: -f 6
unknown

# non-existent disk
$ DEV=/dev/sdc; sudo parted -ms "$DEV" print 2>/dev/null | grep "$DEV" | cut -d: -f 6
# no output
```

Comment: cloud-init does this by [counting](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/37175dd4546c3963583a6583cf0d796a7f70a170/cloudinit/config/cc_disk_setup.py#L419) the [number of partitions returned from lsblk](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/37175dd4546c3963583a6583cf0d796a7f70a170/cloudinit/config/cc_disk_setup.py#L244). If you're just trying to safely initialise a disk for a VM, cloud-init's [disk_setup](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#disk-setup) flag `overwrite: false` might be all you need.

Comment: If you're trying to do this for a data disk with Terraform, you might also run into an issue where cloud-init runs before the disk is attached. In this case, you'll need to tell cloud-init to [wait for the disk](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6117#issuecomment-976428442).